# Excel 2010 array formula cell selection

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Suppose you have a workbook riddled with array formula.

In Excel 2007, if you select any cell (which is part of an array formula), then hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit, you have to go <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to enter the formula (which already exists) as an array formula. When doing this, *all the cells* that are part of the array formula are selected (highlighted).

However, in Excel 2010, this behaviour is different. Repeat the exercise: edit an existing array formula and re-enter with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. Now, only the cells that are in the same column as the edited cell are selected, and only from the top of the array down to the current cell.

An example: suppose cells A1:J10 contain a single array formula. Select cell D6. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. In Excel 2007, the entire range A1:J10 becomes selected. In Excel 2010, only the range D1:D6 is selected.

Is there a way yo get the behaviour from 2007 in 2010? I find this very useful when working on spreadsheets someone else created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 2016 or later, simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. 
(Do this before you press <kbd>F2</kbd>.)

Comment: This seems to work in Excel 2013  as well.

Answer (score 1):

To see the whole group of cells that are linked into a single array formula:

1. Click a cell that contains an array formula that calculates multiple results.
2. On the Home tab, in the Editing group, click the arrow next to Find & Select, and then click Go To Special.
3. In the Go To Special dialog box, click Current array.

This is directly copied from Microsoft. See link: [bit.ly/1xSz1Xc](http://bit.ly/1xSz1Xc)